# Does mcafee mysql audit plugin not work on Percona Server 5.7.27-30?

Tags: mysql, audit, percona

My environment is 5.7.27-30-log Percona Server on CentOS 7.4.
When I installed this plugin (audit-plugin-percona-5.7-1.1.7-866), I got the following error messages.

```
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN AUDIT SONAME 'libaudit_plugin.so';
ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'AUDIT'; Plugin initialization function failed.
```

In mysql error log:

```
2020-05-14T08:15:23.084986Z 222309 [Warning] option 'audit-json-file-bufsize': signed value 0 adjusted to 1
2020-05-14T08:15:23.085006Z 222309 [Warning] option 'plugin-audit-json-file-bufsize': signed value 0 adjusted to 1
2020-05-14T08:15:23.140600Z 222309 [ERROR] Plugin 'AUDIT' init function returned error.
2020-05-14T08:15:23.140624Z 222309 [ERROR] Plugin 'AUDIT' registration as a AUDIT failed.
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Thanks a lot.